# Malicious File Uploads

Tags: c, validation, image-processing

I am working on an online application that will also allow uploads of image files. The server handling the upload is written in C. So I was thinking if it was possible to upload malicious content. I am talking about viruses or malicious code or the like. I will only allow the upload of images so I can check the MIME-type and also the file suffix. But I am not sure if this is enough. The uploaded pictures will be delivered automatically via an HTML `<img>` tag.

I know that in the past images have been used to provoke buffer overflows and other unpleasant stuff. But maybe this isn't my responsibility to check but rather on the end of the browser to not allow image processing to expose vulnerabilities?

**In short:** When offering a service that depends on images provided by the users what can I do to prevent my server of becoming a distribution center of Malware? What are best practices regarding this concern? Would I go ahead and check the uploaded file via a certain algorithm or a certain library? Would that open vulnerabilities on my end? Is it my concern at all?

**Edit:** I may not have been specific of the mode of operation of the file uploading part. It is a module of `nxweb` a server written in `C` as is the module. So I am looking for ways to validate the file in that module.

Comment: Nice question--but possibly outside the scope of Stackoverflow, since you are not serving the code itself. If you serve up an image through HTML, the *client* -- your viewers' web browser -- offers holes to take advantage of. Are you planning to include a verification after an image is uploaded, or are you just going to pass it on?

Comment: That's pretty much my question. Do I have to add a verification at all? If it is needed and feasible I would do it.

Comment: I don't think this question belongs to `Server Fault` as I am specifically asking for a way to check the safety of the uploaded file via a `C` library or something of that nature.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed as off-topic because the answer below is a very good answer that directly involves programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just test your file: Images (to confirm they are images) and executables (to discard them).

In order to test images, you can try open it with ImageMagick or OpenCV or FFmpeg or similar libraries that allow you to open several different formats! If the file can't be open as image, it's not an image!

Testing only images is just fine, but if you wanna test executables to get even more precision result, look for the [PE format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) (Windows), Linux [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), [Mach-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) (Mac OS X) and so on... they are not hard to parse. There's a lot of open source for this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Is it safe to do so though? I mean are there any known weaknesses in the libraries you're suggesting, that would put my server at risk? I know this gets more and more philosophical in the direction of "trusting trust", I just want as much input as possible before deciding how to proceed.

Comment: weakness? hummm... sometimes it may have security failures, of course, but when it happens, everybody is alerted! they are both active projects, open source, so bugs are quickly solved when someone finds one... you choose: you them, or parse the image files by yourself